# Error DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147009287 deploy Windows Phone Universal 10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-phone, win-universal-app, windows-10

When I try to deploy my application to Windows phone 10 I get this error:

> Error: -2147009287 from visual studio 2015 comunity.

How can I solve that?

Comment: this means ERROR_INSTALL_FAILED. Does the phone has all dependencies installed?

Comment: is your phone configured to allow side loading? Also try to activate "device portal" on the phone (settings->update & security->for developers) and open the provided url from your dev device in a browser and deploy the appx package and the dependencies here.

Comment: Have you checked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985599/uwp-deployment-error-after-deploying-to-store-windows-10? Since you are having the same error code (see http://errco.de/win32/winerror-h/error_install_failed/15609/), it might help you.

Comment: hi @jijieciprian, did you get any solution for the error? Because, i am also facing the same issue while deploying it to device.

Comment: hi @Bhanuprakash Mankala, I no find any solution but you can uninstall your application and restart the phone, I made a new solution of my project and seems work fine, I no received any error

Comment: thanks @jijieciprian, i have uninstalled the app and reinstalled, then it is working absolutely fine. But, i am not able to get what is the root cause for that exception.

Comment: I also had to uninstall a previous version of the app before the install would work.

Comment: This error also appears when you have 2 Windows Phones plugged into your machine at the same time while deploying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jay Zuo said in his comments (via a link). The easy way to solve this issue, seems to be to uninstall existing app (which is probably installed from the store) and then try to deploy the app again via Visual Studio.

This worked for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I was using a USB cable that was not in an excellent state, so to speak. I went to the store and got a new one. Using the new USB cable the deploy started to work.

So, for anyone who doesn't know what else to do to fix this, try using another USB cable if you can.