# Cannot deploy UWP app to Win 10 Mobile

Tags: deployment, windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I am writing a UWP app that I want to deploy to the store as a replacement to an existing Win 8.1 app.

The current app that is in the store has packages for Win Phone 7 and Win Phone 8.1 and I want to add a new UWP package for the Win 10 family.

After I run the "associate app with the store" and pick the specific package from my list of packages, I am no longer able to deploy the app to the mobile device. The app still deploys fine on my local Win 10 machine just not on mobile.

`DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147009287`

The app runs fine on the phone if it's not associated to the package on the store so I don't think it's a framework / tools / versioning issue but here are all the versions:

[UPDATE]

- Visual Studio: **2015 Update 3 (14.0.25425)**
- Win 10: **14393.187**
- Mobile: **10.0.10586**
- Sdk: **10.0.10240, 10.0.10586, 10.0.14393, Tools 1.4.1**
- App Min Version: **10.0.10240**
- App Target Version: **10.0.10586**

Comment: what's the version of Visual studio, os and mobile os?

Comment: VS 2015 Update 3 (14.0.25425), Win 10 14393.187, Win 10 Mobile 10.0.10586.164. App min version 10.0.10240, target version 10.0.10586

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your error code, I think you may have the same problem like [Error DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147009287 deploy Windows Phone Universal 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761713/error-dep0001-unexpected-error-2147009287-deploy-windows-phone-universal-10).

To fix this issue, you can try to uninstall the existing app form your mobile manually and then deploy the app again via Visual Studio.

Comment: I was so sure I tried this ... looks like I haven't. It worked. Thanks.